# istream::ignore and getline() confusion

Tags: c++, iostream

I am helping someone with C++ input even though I don't know C++ myself. Here's a short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i;
    string s;

    cout << "enter i:\n";
    cin >> i;
    cout << "enter s:\n";
    getline(cin, s);
    //cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cout << "i: " << i << ", s: " << s << "\n";
}
```

As expected, the `getline()` call will not prompt the user for input because it will simply swallow the trailing `\n` after the `cin >> i` call and return immediately. What I find odd is that if you uncomment the `cin.ignore()` call, the `getline()` call **will** prompt the user for input (even though nothing will be saved into `s`). Could someone explain why? In my view, the line in question should not change the behaviour at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no. It is not the case that "`getline()` will prompt the user for input". Clearly the `ignore` statement comes *after* the `getline()` one.

What happens is that the `ignore()` statement simply blocks until it fulfils its task, i.e. gobble up 100 characters or a newline, whichever comes first (but mind the input buffering).

As a general, though not directly related, piece of advice: don't mix token extraction (`>>`) and `getline()`, for exactly this problem concerning newlines. Much better to just stick to one thing; preferably line reading so you can deal with errors and repeat the prompt. Also consider any unchecked read operation (`>>`, `getline()`, or `istream::read()`) a programming error; there should be conditionals surrounding all of those.

Comment: Thanks. I thought `istream::ignore()` was "non-intrusive" and simply skipped if there was nothing to ignore.

Comment: Why would you think that? Check the [manual](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/): "**extracts** characters". It doesn't say anything about optional stuff. Maybe `readsome()` could be used to implement some look-ahead checking... but it's rarely useful to do so, as I said in my last paragraph.

Comment: Yes, it all makes sense now. Somehow I missed this detail while skimming through the manual.

Answer (score 1):

> What I find odd is that if you uncomment the cin.ignore() call, the
>   getline() call will prompt the user for input

No, it won't.  It's the ignore statement that's prompting the user.  As you have it, it's doing essentially the same thing as getline does, except that it will only read up to 100 characters, and it just throws them away.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `getline` call that's waiting for input, it's the `ignore` one that is waiting for things to ignore.

Put the `ignore` call before the `getline`.